# Apache Solr: How to deal with words composed with numbers

Tags: solr

If I search for any of the following I get the exact sames results:

- iPhone
- iPhone 4
- iPhone 5
- iPhone4
- "iPhone 4"
- (iPhone 4)

How can I force Solr to care about the number following a word?

I tried to add them in the *prodwords.txt*, or the *spellings.txt* but it had no impact, and can't find any useful tip on google.

I'm using Solr 4.6 and have the default Drupal Search API Solr search [schema.xml](http://drupalcode.org/project/search_api_solr.git/blob/HEAD:/solr-conf/4.x/schema.xml) with as only difference that I removed the stemming option.

---

**Working solution:**

To have the field working with this kind of keywords I needed to set minimum token length to 1:

```
<filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100" />
```

But also have these configurations for the *WordDelimiterFilterFactory*

- catenateNumbers="1"
- generateNumberParts="1"

Comment: You're going to have to delve into the world of analyzers and tokenizers.  They affect how Solr indexes your text.  It's not simple.  Start here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

Comment: thanks for the link, let's see how I solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the configuration of fieldType "text" (or other fieldTypes with the similar configuration) in schema.xml file. The minimum length for a token is set to 2:

```
<filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
```

So all your tokens with length one will be removed.

Comment: This is a good point. I should then set min="1". I understand a token is a word length, right?

Comment: Yes, tokens are similar to words in a sentence. So "iPhone 5" when tokenized is converted to two tokens "iPhone" and "5". Actually, how a string is converted to a list of tokens, is determined by your chain of tokenizers configured in your solr. For example, depending on your configuration "iPhone5" might convert to one token, that is "iPhone5", or to two tokens "iPhone" and "5".